# Move one element into another element with remaining elements going to a third location

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to swap elements with the moveButton function. When the user clicks on one of the images is moves the first one to the #good div and then any remaining will go into the #evil div. I have the if/else statement I thought would work.

```
<div id="character">
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function moveButton(elem){
        if( $(elem).parent().attr("id") == "menu" ){
            $(elem).detach().appendTo('#good');
        }
        else{
            $(elem).detach().appendTo('#evil'); 
        }
    }
  </script>    
</div>
<div id="good">

</div>
<div id="evil">

</div>
<div id="menu">
  <div class="character" onclick="moveButton(this)" data-name="Chomper">
    <p>Chomper</p><p><img width="100" src="http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/plantsvszombies/images/a/a3/Chomper1.png/revision/latest?cb=20090521220057" alt=" + Chomper + "></p><p>Hit Points: 3.55</p>
  </div>
  <div class="character" onclick="moveButton(this)" data-name="Kernel-pult">
    <p>Kernel-pult</p><p><img width="100" src="http://vignette4.wikia.nocookie.net/plantsvszombies/images/c/c4/Kernel-pult1.png/revision/latest?cb=20090521220358" alt=" + Kernel-pult + "></p><p>Hit Points: 1.55</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want the icons be removable from evil to good? Do you want the icons stop toggle in evil?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gate your if with a boolean like [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/SaschaKluth/ud6sts0k/)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var good = false;

  function moveButton(elem) {
    if ($(elem).parent().attr("id") == "menu" && !good) {
      $(elem).detach().appendTo('#good');
    } else {
      $(elem).detach().appendTo('#evil');
    }
    good = true;
  }

</script>
```

To send all remaining caracters to evil use `$("#menu").find(".character").detach().appendTo('#evil');`

like in [fiddle 2](https://jsfiddle.net/SaschaKluth/ud6sts0k/1/)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var good = false;

  function moveButton(elem) {
    if ($(elem).parent().attr("id") == "menu" && !good) {
      $(elem).detach().appendTo('#good');
    } else {
      $(elem).detach().appendTo('#evil');
    }

    $("#menu").find(".character").detach().appendTo('#evil');

    good = true;
  }

</script>
```

Comment: Sascha, Thank you for your answer that seemed to work if i continue to click on the elements. I wanted to know if it was possible to move all the remaining elements to the evil section when i click the good guy. Thank you again.

Comment: Yes it is. I adapted the fiddle for you. See the extended answer above.

Answer (score 0):

Do not pass THIS to your function, it's already there in the scope. Also using detach() method, you are removing elements from DOM. Try the following...

```
function moveButton() {
    if( $(this).parent().attr("id") == "menu" ) {
        $(this).appendTo('#good');
    } else {
        $(this).appendTo('#evil'); 
    }
}
```